# Applying javascript to an ajax quicktab result

Tags: ajax, javascript, blocks

I have made an interface with some quite sophisticated functionality - tabs ([module Quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs)), containing views ([module Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) from nested taxonomy ([module views tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree)), containing tables which are views ([module Views field view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)). All very satisfying and really demonstrates to me the power of Drupal.

Since the tabs are such heavy-weight views, I am loading them with AJAX. I want to apply some JQuery operations to the views after they have loaded - things that don't seem possible to do within views itself (removing elements of the taxonomy tree that don't contain tables) but are very easy to do with JQuery. My question is - how do I efficiently execute the Jquery after the AJAX tab has loaded? I'm guessing I need to add the following into the theme:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // apply jQuery here
});
```

but this seems like it might be very inefficient (getting called every time ajax is used anywhere on the site).

Any advice gratefully accepted!

Drupal rocks - it's amazing what you can do without having to dig into the code.

Comment: You may be over-thinking this...as long as you only introduce this code on the pages it belongs on, _getting called every time ajax is used anywhere on the site_ is no longer a worry. And even if you don't, have you thought about the performance impact of that in real terms? We're probably talking on the level of microseconds. The Drupal way to do it is with behaviors, by the way, but those are also invoked every time "something" happens as well

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about Behaviours, I need to refresh myself on that. I will do the Drupalizeme tutorials on them and work out how to execute the ajaxComplete only on the relevant pages.